# Why did they reverse the propellers' rotation?

Tags: plot-explanation, poseidon

In [*Poseidon* (2006)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0409182/), Robert Ramsey died while stopping the propellers.

But the propellers started in a reverse direction, which creates suction. (**I don't know who reversed it.**) Dylan stuck a cylinder into the propeller with which damages it.

[image]

They finally get out of the ship. But Ramsey never was informed that he will reverse the propellers.

Why did they reverse the propellers' rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why did they reverse the propellers' rotation?

### To get out since the power of the thrusters was blowing them back...

[**IMDB Synopsis**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0409182/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl)

> Nelson sees the door to the bow thrusters and opens it, only to get **blown back by the hurricane-force winds the still-active propellor is generating**. While Jen looks after him, Christian suggests throwing something in there to block the propellers and get them to stop, but **Ramsey points out they'd need to either stop them manually or get them turning the other way**.

As for who reversed it...it was Robert Ramsey

> Ramsey dives in and swims off. The other three arrive and are told what Ramsey is doing as we see Ramsey get in the control room. **He finds the engine stop button, but it's broken**. He starts running out of air, and with his last breath manages to **find the button to make the propellers turn the other way**.